# identifying an SMD component (marked as 1J15)

Tags: diodes, identification, surface-mount

I'm having issues identifying a SMD component (the one marked with "1J15"). The component is a part of a differential circuit breaker. Here's the picture :

[image]

Its length is 2.7mm. To me, it is a diode (I tested them with a diode tester; they are dead as they are shorted).

Comment: Put the part number in the question title so that anyone who recognises it will be attracted by the title. In the post you could give some context. What type of device is the component mounted in? Judging by the stripe on the component and on the PCB silkscreen I'd say you are correct to treat them as diodes.

Comment: Thank you @Transistor, I added the modifications you asked me.

Comment: "*The component is a part of a differential circuit breaker ...*" I'd be OK with repairing the device for educational purposes but I wouldn't use it to protect a house - even a father-in-law's one!

Comment: I agree with you. I won't repair it. He wants to do that anyway :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From searching on [The ultimate SMD marking codes database](https://smd.yooneed.one/code314a.html) for codes starting `1J` it could be a [GS1006FL](https://www.wontop.com/smd-1408614901.html) from Won-Top Electronics (or possibly now part of PANJIT International). This is Diode Rectifier, 600V, 1A, Vf<1.1V(1A), 4pF

The [datasheet](https://www.wontop.com/uploadfiles/56/sort_excel/pdf/gs1000fl.pdf) shows the marking as 1J:

[image]

The package is a `SOD-123FL` which has a length of 2.60 mm (min) to 2.95 mm (max).

Comment: Nice one, here is the panjit datasheet: https://www.panjit.com.tw/upload/datasheet/GS1000FL_SERIES.pdf and https://assets.lcsc.com/images/lcsc/900x900/20190109_PANJIT-International-GS1004FL-AU-R1-000A1_C360743_front.jpg a picture of a neighbor designation

Comment: I'm amazed how fast you found the solution. We spent hours on the internet to find nothing :)

Comment: @Maxime smd.yooneed.one is a very handy page to have bookmarked.